# Не удалось изменить возвращаемое значение "Matrix3X2F.Fields", т. к. оно не является переменной

Tags: c#, .net, матрицы, struct

Описываю структуру матрицы `3x2`. Ну думаю упрощу себе и другим жизнь, напишу индексатор по колонке и строке.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Matrix3X2F
{
    [field: FieldOffset(0)] public MatrixFields Fields { get; set; }

    private float this[uint row, uint column]
    {
        get
        {
            if (row > 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row),
                    "A \"Matrix 3x2\" row cannot be greater than 2.");
            }

            if (column > 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column),
                    "A \"Matrix 3x2\" column cannot be greater than 1.");
            }

            switch (row)
            {
                case 0 when column == 0:
                    return Fields.M11;
                case 0 when column == 1:
                    return Fields.M12;
                case 1 when column == 0:
                    return Fields.M21;
                case 1 when column == 1:
                    return Fields.M22;
                case 2 when column == 0:
                    return Fields.M31;
                case 2 when column == 1:
                    return Fields.M32;
                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        set
        {
            if (row > 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row),
                    "A \"Matrix 3x2\" row cannot be greater than 2.");
            }

            if (column > 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column),
                    "A \"Matrix 3x2\" column cannot be greater than 1.");
            }

            switch (row)
            {
                case 0 when column == 0:
                    Fields.M11 = value;
                    break;
                case 0 when column == 1:
                    Fields.M12 = value;
                    break;
                case 1 when column == 0:
                    Fields.M21 = value;
                    break;
                case 1 when column == 1:
                    Fields.M22 = value;
                    break;
                case 2 when column == 0:
                    Fields.M31 = value;
                    break;
                case 2 when column == 1:
                    Fields.M32 = value;
                    break;
                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct MatrixFields
    {
        [field: FieldOffset(0)] public float M11 { get; set; }
        [field: FieldOffset(4)] public float M12 { get; set; }
        [field: FieldOffset(8)] public float M21 { get; set; }
        [field: FieldOffset(12)] public float M22 { get; set; }
        [field: FieldOffset(16)] public float M31 { get; set; }
        [field: FieldOffset(20)] public float M32 { get; set; }
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что вернуть значение можно, но вот присвоить нельзя. Почему так происходит. и можно ли решить эту проблему?

При сборке ошибка `CS1612`:

> error CS1612: Не удалось изменить возвращаемое значение
>   "Matrix3X2F.Fields", т. к. оно не является переменной.

P.S. Вообще хотелось бы возвращать значения по ссылке, и изменять их, а не копировать...

P.S.S. Ну а пока я покажу свой костыль `:)`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetValue(this ref GCHandle handle, float value, int offset = 0)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        IntPtr tmpPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, IntPtr.Add(tmpPtr, offset), bytes.Length);
        handle.Free();
        handle = default;
    }
}
```

А дальше:

```
public float this[uint row, uint column]
{
    get
    {
        if (row > 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row),
                "A \"Matrix 3x2\" row cannot be greater than 2.");
        }

        if (column > 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column),
                "A \"Matrix 3x2\" column cannot be greater than 1.");
        }

        switch (row)
        {
            case 0 when column == 0:
                return Fields.M11;
            case 0 when column == 1:
                return Fields.M12;
            case 1 when column == 0:
                return Fields.M21;
            case 1 when column == 1:
                return Fields.M22;
            case 2 when column == 0:
                return Fields.M31;
            case 2 when column == 1:
                return Fields.M32;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    set
    {
        if (row > 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row),
                "A \"Matrix 3x2\" row cannot be greater than 2.");
        }

        if (column > 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column),
                "A \"Matrix 3x2\" column cannot be greater than 1.");
        }

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        switch (row)
        {
            case 0 when column == 0:
                handle.SetValue(value);
                break;
            case 0 when column == 1:
                handle.SetValue(value, 4);
                break;
            case 1 when column == 0:
                handle.SetValue(value, 8);
                break;
            case 1 when column == 1:
                handle.SetValue(value, 12);
                break;
            case 2 when column == 0:
                handle.SetValue(value, 16);
                break;
            case 2 when column == 1:
                handle.SetValue(value, 20);
                break;
            default:
                handle.Free();
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Который не сработал...

Comment: Сделать вместо свойства поле: `public MatrixFields Fields;`

Comment: А что насчет ссылки? Через `unsafe` контекст я могу ее вернуть, но в другом случае нет.

Comment: Опишите чуть подробнее конечную цель. Для чего вообще задан `StructLayout`? Эти структуры используются для интеропа?

Comment: Раз уж вы упоминаете `unsafe` и не хотите лишних расходов на копирование, то может стоит сделать поле `[FieldOffset(0)] public fixed float Matrix[6];` в структуре `MatrixFields`? Естественно, придётся работать с указателями в небезопасном контексте.

Comment: Опять же, если заботиться о производительности, то я бы все свойства заменил на поля. А если совсем заморочиться, то стоит смотреть в сторону `ref struct`.

Answer (score 1):

Одно из возможных решений. Сделаем локальную копию `Fields`, поменяем ей нужное поле и присвоим эту копию свойству `Fields`.

Метод `set` будет следующим:

```
set
{
    if (row > 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row),
            "A \"Matrix 3x2\" row cannot be greater than 2.");
    }

    if (column > 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column),
            "A \"Matrix 3x2\" column cannot be greater than 1.");
    }

    var tmp = Fields;

    switch (row)
    {
        case 0 when column == 0:
            tmp.M11 = value;
            Fields = tmp;
            break;
        case 0 when column == 1:
            tmp.M12 = value;
            break;
        case 1 when column == 0:
            tmp.M21 = value;
            break;
        case 1 when column == 1:
            tmp.M22 = value;
            break;
        case 2 when column == 0:
            tmp.M31 = value;
            break;
        case 2 when column == 1:
            tmp.M32 = value;
            break;
        default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    Fields = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Не выгодно, расходы на копирование.

Comment: @ヒミコ Так и есть, невыгодно. Но мне кажется, что делать структуру изменяемой - сомнительное решение. Может быть, вам все же стоит сделать Matrix3X2F классом?

Answer (score 0):

Пока сделал так, но может есть другой способ вернуть значение по ссылке?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 4)]
public struct Matrix3X2F
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public MatrixFields Fields;

    public ref float this[uint row, uint column] // BUG: return value by ref, but this work with unsafe context.
    {
        get
        {
            if (row > 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row),
                    "A \"Matrix 3x2\" row cannot be greater than 2.");
            }

            if (column > 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column),
                    "A \"Matrix 3x2\" column cannot be greater than 1.");
            }

            unsafe
            {
                fixed (Matrix3X2F* matrix = &this)
                {
                    switch (row)
                    {
                        case 0 when column == 0:
                            return ref matrix->Fields.M11;
                        case 0 when column == 1:
                            return ref matrix->Fields.M12;
                        case 1 when column == 0:
                            return ref matrix->Fields.M21;
                        case 1 when column == 1:
                            return ref matrix->Fields.M22;
                        case 2 when column == 0:
                            return ref matrix->Fields.M31;
                        case 2 when column == 1:
                            return ref matrix->Fields.M32;
                        default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Fields.M11:N1} {Fields.M21:N1} {Fields.M31:N1}\n{Fields.M12:N1} {Fields.M22:N1} {Fields.M32:N1}";
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct MatrixFields
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public float M11;
        [FieldOffset(4)] public float M12;
        [FieldOffset(8)] public float M21;
        [FieldOffset(12)] public float M22;
        [FieldOffset(16)] public float M31;
        [FieldOffset(20)] public float M32;
    }
}
```